# Unable to read from/write to an NFS share from Win XP client

Tags: linux, windows-xp, nfs

We have an NFS share on a Debian Linux host which is mounted on a Win XP host using SFU. We can create folders on a share or delete files from it but it's not possible to perform file write or read operations on it (say, `copy file.ext n:\` blocks for a long time and finally terminates with `The remote system refused the network connection` error). We tried both TCP and UDP on a client side when mounting. All ports are open on firewall between these two machines. There is nothing relevant in Win XP Event Log and in syslog on a server side. And this is not a permission problem obviously because we can create folders. What can we do to find a root cause of this?

**Update:** I captured an NFS session using Wireshark and found that the root cause was a locking problem, the NFS server keeped answering NFS_DENIED_GRACE_PERIOD status to client calls. And the question now is how to fix this locking issue?

Comment: does it reproduce with a linux client? If not - open a case with MS, or switch to another protocol. SFU are notorious for being godawful

Comment: The Linux client works like a charm so the problem seems to be Windows-specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

99.9999% of the time when something says connection refused it has something to do with either the software or the hardware firewall. I suggest you telnet first to the ports in question from source to destination and check.

Comment: You are right, it was the Windows firewall. We had to disable it completely to make NFS client work.